# npm install doesnt create dist folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, grafana

I am following this tutorial [link](http://grafana.org/blog/2016/04/08/clock-plugin-p1.html) to create a grafana plugin.

But when I copy this code [link](https://github.com/grafana/clock-panel/tree/6a9d0d625e3757582ce30f0b5c7e784a2b0e978b) from the tutorial to my test server(without the `dist/` folder) and run `npm install` npm doesn’t create a new `dist/` folder instead it creates a `node_modules` folder.

Am I missing a step here or am I understanding something incorrect? Since I expected that command to create a `dist/` folder out of the files in the `src/` folder?

The grunt file:

```
module.exports = (grunt) => {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-execute');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

  grunt.initConfig({

    clean: ['dist'],

    copy: {
      src_to_dist: {
        cwd: 'src',
        expand: true,
        src: ['**/*', '!**/*.js', '!**/*.scss'],
        dest: 'dist'
      },
      pluginDef: {
        expand: true,
        src: [ 'plugin.json', 'README.md' ],
        dest: 'dist',
      }
    },

    watch: {
      rebuild_all: {
        files: ['src/**/*', 'plugin.json'],
        tasks: ['default'],
        options: {spawn: false}
      },
    },

    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        presets: ['es2015'],
        plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-systemjs', 'transform-es2015-for-of'],
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          cwd: 'src',
          expand: true,
          src: ['*.js'],
          dest: 'dist',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
    },

  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'copy:src_to_dist', 'copy:pluginDef', 'babel']);
};
```

The package.json:

```
{
  "name": "clock-panel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Clock Panel Plugin for Grafana",
  "main": "src/module.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --color .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "clock",
    "grafana",
    "plugin",
    "panel"
  ],
  "author": "Raintank",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "~6.5.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^2.5.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.4.0",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-babel": "~6.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.8.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-execute": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-systemjs-builder": "^0.2.5",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~3.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "~4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.12.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help anyone, but I was manually copying files from an existing project to a new one and forgot to copy over `index.js`, which had the code for bundling into `dist` with `serve-static`. Was following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/ilejohn/deploy-vue-3-app-to-heroku-via-github-4a49)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing running `grunt` default task

You should run:

`npm install` (which installs your dependencies), followed by a `grunt` (which copies src files to dist as you can see in the Gruntfile.js `copy:src_to_dist` task)

So in short just run: `$ npm install && grunt`

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` command installs packages that your project will be using as dependencies. It will create the `node_modules` directory in your current directory (if one doesn't exist yet), and will download the package to that directory.

Comment: `npm install` has nothing to do with creating (or failing to create) the `dist` folder, which is what OP is asking about.

Comment: @mrodo, well actually, there is a `prepublish` feature which is sometimes used to move files to the dist folder.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, running an `npm install` will also execute the `prepublish` of your `package.json` if there is one.

For your needs, it sounds like you want to do this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "grunt",
    "prepublish": "npm run build"
  },
```