# 'dist' folder is not generated while doing npm build in a Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I usually write Dockerfiles for Java / Go applications and it's the first time I have encountered a situation where I have to write a Dockerfile for an already existing (and production running) Node.js application. As per my little knowledge about the Node.js which I acquired in the past couple of days, **dist** folder is generated after we build a Node.js project which carries the source code (please correct me if I am wrong here). So I am interested in copying the **dist** folder from parent Docker image to child Docker image.

However, after I copy everything from an application into my parent Docker image (line 6) and run 'npm run build' command, dist folder is not generated for me (please note the **node_modules** and package-lock.json are being generated).

My Dockerfile is as below:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as BUILD
WORKDIR /src
COPY package*.json /src
RUN apk add --update --no cache \
    python \
    make \
    g++
RUN npm install
COPY . /src
RUN npm run build
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does it work outside of Docker?  What do or don't you see?  What does the `"build"` command do inside your `package.json` file?

Comment: @DavidMaze - Hi, I just tried locally building the project and I am surprised to see that even when I locally build it, **dist** folder is not getting generated. Not sure what would be the reason behind this (please note that node_modules and package-lock,json is generated). Also, I didn't get any error post build and **Compiled Successfully** message was shown. Coming to your 2nd point - build command inside package.json is written as - "build" = "next build". Please let me know if you need any additional information

Comment: You may find the following reading interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975500/npm-install-doesnt-create-dist-folder

Comment: @Zeitounator - I went through the article and modified Dockerfile to include below 2 commands - ```RUN npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN npm install grunt``` just before the line ```COPY . /src```. Still I am not able to see dist folder generated in my docker image

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using typescript in your node application then follow these instructions.

Please add the below entry under **compilerOptions** section on "tsconfig.json"

> tsconfig.json

`**"outDir": "./dist/"**`

> package.json - Add the below script too.

`"scripts": { "build": "tsc" }`

Now, re-run the "npm run build". You will see the dist folder.

Comment: do you mean `"outDir": "./dist/"` and not `**"outDir": "./dist/"**`.

Answer (score 1):

Try by ignoring the 'tsconfig.tsbuildinfo' file.
don't copy this file into docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone using `nestjs`, Oddly in my `Dockerfile` I had `RUN npm run build` and was not pulling any folders/files besides tsconfig.build.tsbuildinfo, once I made it `RUN npx nest build` it copied all of the files over.