# How can I deploy Node JS app along with dist folder for production in Kubernetes?

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

The Node JS app that I'm trying to deploy in Kubernetes runs on `express js` as a backend framework.The repository is managed via `Bitbucket`. The application is a microservice and the pipeline manifest file for building the Docker image is written this way:

```
options:
  docker: true
image: node:14.17.0
pipelines:
  branches:
    test:
      - step:
          services:
           - docker
          name: Build and push new docker image
          deployment: dev
          script:
            - yarn install
            - yarn build
            - yarn test
            - yarn lint
            - make deploy.dev
            - docker login -u $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
            - docker build -t testapp/helloapp:latest -f ./Dockerfile .
            - docker push testapp/helloapp
          caches:
            - docker # adds docker layer caching
```

The K8s cluster is hosted on [cloud](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/deploy-kubernetes-using-kubespray/) but does not have the internal `Load Balancer` of their own. The K8s cluster version is `v1.22.4` and `MetalLB v0.11.0` is configured to serve the Load Balancing purpose. To expose the K8s `service`- Cloudflare Tunnel is configured as a K8s `deployment`.

So, this is the manifest file set-up used for building the Docker image. The pipeline deploys successfully and in the Kubernetes part, this is the `service` and `deployment` manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: helloapp
 labels:
   app: helloapp
spec:
 type: NodePort
 ports:
 - port: 5000
   targetPort: 7000
   protocol: TCP
   name: https
 selector:
   app: helloapp

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloapp
  labels:
    app: helloapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: helloapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloapp
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      containers:
      - name: helloapp
        image: testapp/helloapp:latest
```

Also, here is the `Dockerfile` snippet to give more clarity on what I have been doing:

```
FROM node:14.17.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

CMD node app.js

EXPOSE 8100
```

Just to give a context, the service and deployment works fine, with no `CrashLoopBackOff` or any other errors.
My doubt here is, there is `dist` directory which is not getting deployed to Docker Hub as it is generated during `npm build`. How can I deploy the app along with the `dist` directory without having to worry about security risks? Any feedbacks and suggestions on where I could add a script to pull the `dist` directory would be appreciated.

Comment: What’s your Dockerfile?

Comment: @Isolated updated

Comment: Update your Dockerfile to COPY dist to /app instead of everything.

Comment: “without having to worry about security risks”, what security risks are you worried about? Are you copying across sensitive files? (.env for example)

Comment: There are some stuffs inside dist which are part of .ENV file. So, that's something I was referring to.

Comment: which files are added to dist? If your .env is being moved to dist then that is an issue. You can inject environment variables using both Docker and Kubernetes. You could also add .env to .dockerignore (in addition to any other sensitive files, although I prefer to be explicit) https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak updated.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Do you have some errors and logs?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak when I hit `curl http://a.b.c.d:30001`, the connection gets refused. I know the issue is because I am not able to import `dist` directory to K8s. So, what I'm asking is how can I copy `dist` directory- because what I have tried is a multitude of options; including the removal of `dist` directory from `.gitignore`. Also, similarly I tried the answer accepted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693994/dist-folder-is-not-generated-while-doing-npm-build-in-a-dockerfile) and it does not work in my case.

Comment: what is the exact returned result from `curl`? Is is possible to hardcode your directory inside your image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I could resolve the issue. The issue was trivial yet bothering. In the `Dockerfile`, there was a missing script, i.e., `npm run build`. So, here is the final `Dockerfile` I used it for building the `dist` directory along with other requirements:

```
FROM node:14.17.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build <------ the missing script

COPY . /app

CMD node app.js

EXPOSE 8100
```

This way, the entire `dist` directory gets built inside the container. Also, I removed all the `.ENV` dependencies from `dist` directory and stored as Kubernetes secret in `base64` format.